# Php fails to return JSON array to Android app

Tags: php, android, json, http

I am attempting to write a simple app that requires users to create an account. I decided to use mysql / php for the backend and Android to create the actual app. The user can enter their username and password from the app and the backend would store it in the database. Then, a json array will be returned to the app. Unfortunately, the code that I have is not working. The app simply crashes and nothing is getting printed on the log.

Here is the Php:

```
$json = array();
$master = array();
$json['status'] = "fail";
$json['message'] = "unable to connect to the server";
$master['master'] = $json;
echo json_encode($master);
exit;
```

Here is the android code. I am using an AsyncTask class to do the networking. This is the function that does the work:

```
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urls[0]);
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try
        {

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("method", "create"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = Client.execute(httppost);

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            // Read Server Response
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                // Append server response in string
                sb.append(line + "");
            }

             // Append Server Response To Content String lol
            Content = sb.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Error = ex.getMessage();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                reader.close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex) 
            {

            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

This combination causes a crash. I have verified that the request reaches the server. Can anyone provide some insight?

Comment: "unable to connect to the server" coming from the server, **** the police..

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($master);
```